# Load a YAML file with variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb, chatbot

I'm building a chatbot and storing my 'replies' in a Yaml file below:

```
# say_hello.yml

- reply_type: text
  text: "Welcome <%= @user.first_name %>"
- reply_type: delay
  duration: 2
- reply_type: text
  text: "We're here to help you learn more about something or another."
- reply_type: delay
  duration: 2
```

In order to run the replies I use this method:

```
def process

  @user = User.find(user_id)
  replies = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("app/bot/replies/say_hello.yml")).result)

  replies.each do |reply|
    # code for replies...
  end

end
```

When I run this however I'm getting a 'undefined method' error on `first_name` for `@user`. If I run the same code in a console it works.

How can I define a variable like `@user` and then load the YAML file correctly?

Comment: What error is that _exactly_? undefined method first name for nil:NilClass?

Comment: Yup sorry full error: `undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [format specifications](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-25) instead of ERB.

This leads to a simpler syntax in the YAML file

```
- reply_type: text
  text: "Welcome %{user_name}"
```

and a simple read method

```
@user = User.find(user_id)
replies = YAML.load(
  File.read("app/bot/replies/say_hello.yml") % { user_name: @user.first_name }
)
```

Comment: This is great but ideally I want to pass in a `@user` variable s oI can call `@user.first_name` or `@user.last_name` without defining everything first

Comment: Figured out a way using `binding` ... What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a way using `binding`. YAML load line with the below and it works great:

```
replies = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("app/bot/replies/say_hello.yml")).result(binding))
```

Comment: That's another option. Depends on who is managing the YAML files. External translators (non-developers) might mess up ERB because their syntax is a bit more complex. And it might lead to security issues if you cannot trust the editor of the YAML files.

Comment: @MikeHolford what is binding here? i am also trying to pass some variable inside .yml.erb file . Can you provide details please?