# Trying to parse my password details into yaml, Instead of entering it manually

Tags: ruby, yaml

I’m storing my password and connection strings in yaml file before. Now, I’m trying to store my password in local drive in ".txt" format and parse it to the yaml file. If anyone can help me in what way to approach in parsing would be helpful.

Below are the password details and connection strings used in `yaml` file which I created.

```
app_server_name: ************
app_server_username: $USERNAME$
app_server_password: ‘**********’ #trying to parse from local drive
app_yaml_file: /devl/galaxy/common/edwEnvironmentConfig.yml
environment_profile: /home/$USERNAME$/eproduct/difenv
teradata_logon_file: /home/$USERNAME$/.priv/devl/.td_connection
project_root_directory: /home/$USERNAME$/eproduct/
teradata_auth_type: ‘ldap’
tmode: ‘TERA’
```

What I Found:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html

Also using the psych gem:
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Psych.html

I expect to parse my password details into yaml instead of manually entering it.

Comment: You've described your end goal but you haven't shown us what you've tried, nor asked a question or indicated what problem you're having. Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far and the specifics of your problem.

Comment: Hi Jordan thanks for your reply. I haven't tried much coz i have no idea how to put them together. But, I have researched about it.I will edit the question on what i found. I haven't used much of parsing the .txt file to yaml file.

Comment: Related: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/179125 2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/55104522/179125